# Avoid passing environment variable to python script

Tags: bash, python, environment-variables, python3, shebang

I have a small python script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import some_python3_module

def main():
    # do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and cannot run this script with Python3, since ROS sets the `PYTHONPATH` variable to some version 2.7.-related locations, meaning Python 3 cannot find any modules in its `dist-packages` directory. I would like to override this behaviour without having to modify the outside envorinment. That is, I wish to `unset PYTHONPATH`, but only for this script, and preferably from within it, so that the shebang will still work.
Is this possible?

*Not sure if this is better suited to superuser.com*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a command line option that suits your needs:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 -E
```

> -E
>
> Ignore all PYTHON* environment variables, e.g. PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME, that might be set.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit old but I was looking around for the specific solution I found for this problem:
It turns out this is the actual purpose of using /usr/bin/env

```
#!/usr/bin/env -u PYTHONPATH python3
```

This accomplishes the desired *unset*, then runs python3

From man 1 env:

```
ENV(1)                                    User Commands                                    ENV(1)

NAME
       env - run a program in a modified environment
.
.<snip>
.
       -u, --unset=NAME
              remove variable from the environment
```